# Read EventBridge event output JSON using Lambda python

Tags: python, lambda, amazon-rds, aws-event-bridge

I need some help with filtering some data from a EventBridge Notification. Currently, we have an EventBridge "RDS Cluster Event" Rule with Target = SNS. So, whenever an RDS Cluster even is encountered, we get email notification via SNS but there is too much info in the json email and we want to format it. Current email:

```
{
    "version":"0",
    "id":"xxxxx-xxx-xxx-x-x-x-x",
    "detail-type":"RDS DB Cluster Event",
    "source":"aws.rds",
    "account":"0000000000000",
    "time":"2030-04-29T99:99:18Z",
    "region":"xx-xxx-xx",
    "resources":["arnxxx:xxx:cluster:db-cluster"],
    "detail":{
        "EventCategories":["configuration change"],
        "SourceType":"CLUSTER",
        "SourceArn":"arnxxx:xxx:cluster:db-cluster",
        "Date":"2030-04-29T99:99:18Z",
        "Message":"This is a test",
        "SourceIdentifier":"db-cluster",
        "EventID":"RDS-EVENT-0000"
        }
}
```

I want to filter out the content from this json in the email and get an email like:

```
EventCategories: configuration change
Date: 2030-04-29T99:99:18Z
Message: This is a test
SourceIdentifier: db-cluster
region: xx-xxx-xx
account: 0000000000000
```

Need help with parsing the eventbridge incoming json logs and change the output to above shown and then receive the formatted output in my email (using SNS).

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try below workaround.

print(event['detail'])

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).